# Deploy Static web Content : Apache Server

Tags: apache

What are some of the ways to deploy static web content in Apache server directly from an IDE say Netbeans?

Answer (score 1):

The NetBeans IDE includes [FTP](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/ftp_support_added) and [SFTP support](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/sftp_support_added) (use SFTP to avoid sending your credentials in plaintext).